# Let $z_n = x_n + y_n$, with $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ strictly increasing. Prove that if $(z_n)$ is bounded above, then so are $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be strictly increasing sequences, and let $(z_n)$ be a sequence defined by $z_n = x_n + y_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Prove that if $(z_n)$ is bounded above, then so are $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$.

I do not know where to start with this problem.
I know that $(z_n)$ being bounded above means there exists some $A \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $z_n < A$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, therefore $x_n + y_n < A$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I don't see how this helps finding some $B \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n < B$ (or $y_n < B$).

I have also tried proving the contrapositive but it did not get me anywhere.

Comment: A 'reductio ad absurdum' seems to be a nice approach...

Comment: Hint: Note that $z_n > x_n + y_0$, so $x_n < z_n - y_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be a bound for $(z_n)_n$. Then $M-y_0$ is a bound for $(x_n)_n$ (and similary, $M-x_0$ a bound for $(y_n)_n$):
$$x_n=z_n-y_n\le z_n-y_0\le M-y_0. $$

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $(x_n)_n$ is not bounded from above. Then $x_n \to\infty$ so
$$z_n = x_n + y_n > x_n + y_1 \to \infty$$
Hence $(z_n)_n$ is not bounded from above.

Answer (score 2):

One has $x_n = z_n - y_n$. The sequence $(z_n)$ is bounded above, and the sequence $(y_n)$ is inreasing, so $(-y_n)$ is decreasing so it's also bounded above. So $(x_n)$ is the sum of two sequences that are bounded above, so it is bounded above.

You can do the same for $(y_n)$.